# Como enviar parâmetros do formulário ao invés do JSON em angular?

Tags: php, angularjs, formulário, post

Estou  tentando enviar um `POST` via angular, da mesma maneira que eu fazia no `JQuery`, porém, ao tentar capturar os dados via variável `$_POST`, não está trazendo nenhum valor.

Eu estou executando um código parecido com esse no *angular*:

```
$http.post('/users/ajax-create', user).then(...);
```

O angular parece estar enviando os dados sem a formatação necessária para que o PHP processe os parâmetros para a variável `$_POST`.

Eu só consigo obter os valores se eu fizer assim:

```
 json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
```

Mas o comportamento acima não é desejado. Eu gostaria de usar o *angularjs* na minha aplicação php, porém não gostaria de reescrevê-la ou começar a fazer coisas diferentes só por causa dessa particularidade do *angular*.

Existe alguma maneira de enviar os dados de um objeto javascript pelo *angular*, mas como parâmetros de um formulário `form-url-encoded`?

Observação: Se esse for um comportamento padrão do angular, não gostaria de ficar escrevendo nenhum código a cada projeto que eu implementasse o angular. Então se houver alguma biblioteca pronta que converta os dados para `form-url-encoded`, ficarei satisfeito se houver uma indicação.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o serviço `$httpParamSerializer` para modificar um objeto e prepará-lo para envio, en conjunto com um cabeçalho específico indicando o tipo *form-urlencoded*.

```
$scope.submitForm = function(data) {
  $http({
  method  : 'POST',
  url     : 'process.php',
  data    : $httpParamSerializer(data),
  headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }  // Necessário para especificar o tipo de conteúdo
 })
  .then(function(data) {
  });
};
```

Fontes:
 - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$httpParamSerializer
 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33065986/angular-js-httpparamserializer-and-jquery-ajax

Comment: Boa solução, eu não conhecia o serviço `$httpParamSerializer`.

Comment: @RodrigoRigotti Angular tem vários serviços de suporte, geramente eu preciso checar se não estou reinventando a roda.

Comment: @OnoSendai reportei o [bug no meta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5163/bug-ao-linkar-url-que-contenha). Olha como ficou a url na resposta.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters *nice catch!*

Comment: Arrumei e estraguei o post do meta :P

Answer (score 3):

Você precisa passar o cabeçalho `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` na requisição, além de reescrever o corpo da requisição de modo que não se transmita um JSON.

Assim sendo, no método `$http` faça assim:

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: url,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    transformRequest: function(obj) {
        var str = [];
        for (var p in obj) {
            str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
        }
        return str.join("&");
    },
    data: xsrf
});
```

Comment: Sei que talvez não seja comum isso no Angular, mas em casos de formulários com  `arrays`, essa função não funcionará corretamente.

Comment: Será mesmo? Fiz um teste aqui na função `encodeURIComponent` com um valor do tipo `a[b]` e ele converte para `a%5Bb%5D`, que é a forma certa de se enviar arrays via form data.

Comment: Faz sentido sua colocação. Na verdade, a função só não faz a mesma coisa que `$.param` do jQuery faz. Se quiser adicionar ele como referência na resposta, também será legal